# Pandas dataframe in python: Removing rows from df1 based on rows in df2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
df1: contains all information
rowname a  b  c  d
R1      1  2  0  1
R2      2  2  0  1
R3      0  2  0  0
R4      1  2  0  1

df2: contains a subset of the rows and columns:
rowname a  b  c  
R1      1  2  0  
R2      2  2  0   
R4      1  2  0
```

I want to filter out all the rows `df2` that are not in `df1`. So for this case, I'm looking to get rid of R3 in `df1` while keeping all columns.

I think using `df1.merge(df2, ...)` could work to make this happen, but I've tried a variety of arguments with no success. I'm using python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpy filter the dataframe using `isin()`

```
df1[df1.rowname.isin(df2.rowname)]

  rowname  a  b  c  d
0      R1  1  2  0  1
1      R2  2  2  0  1
3      R4  1  2  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, which matches only on columns `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df = df.loc[df.duplicated(['a', 'b', 'c'], keep=False)]\
       .dropna(subset=['d'], axis=0)

df['d'] = df['d'].astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d rowname
0  1  2  0  1      R1
1  2  2  0  1      R2
3  1  2  0  1      R4
```